# How to bitwise replace a range of bits in one number with the bits of another for incrementing, not affecting lower bits?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I have a 16-bit number, the LSB 4 bits are used as bitfields to check settings, and the MSB 12 bits are used as a `number` that is incremented.
I know that `tempNum = (data_bits >> 4)` will get me the `number` out of the larger one. If I want to increment that `tempNum` by 1 and then put that back into the overall 16-bit number as a replacement without affecting the lower 4 bits, how would I go about doing this? I want to do this using `bitwise` operations only.

Comment: " I want to do this using bitwise operations only." -->   What real use case needs this restriction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to increment starting after 4 bits, i.e.:

```
data_bits += 1 << 4;
```

This leaves the lower 4 bits unchanged.